# Magento2: how can i override protected function

Tags: magento2, category, import, topmenu

i want to override `CategoryProcessor.php` `namespace Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product;`

I have created my custom module but not override.

my registration file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magenticians_Showcategory',
    __DIR__
);
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "Magenticians/Showcategory",
    "description": "remove category on menu when import the product csv",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "Commercial"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magenticians\\Showcategory\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magenticians_Showcategory" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor" type="Magenticians\Showcategory\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor" />
</config>
```

CategoryProcessor.php overrided . 
**"just change true to false in include in menue"**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 namespace Magenticians\Showcategory\Model\Import\Product;

/**
 * Class CategoryProcessor
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class CategoryProcessor
{
    /**
     * Delimiter in category path.
     */
    const DELIMITER_CATEGORY = '/';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $categoryColFactory;

    /**
     * Categories text-path to ID hash.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $categories = [];

    /**
     * Categories id to object cache.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $categoriesCache = [];

    /**
     * Instance of catalog category factory.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * Failed categories during creation
     *
     * @var array
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $failedCategories = [];

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryColFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryColFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryColFactory = $categoryColFactory;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->initCategories();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function initCategories()
    {
        if (empty($this->categories)) {
            $collection = $this->categoryColFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path');
            /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                $structure = explode(self::DELIMITER_CATEGORY, $category->getPath());
                $pathSize = count($structure);

                $this->categoriesCache[$category->getId()] = $category;
                if ($pathSize > 1) {
                    $path = [];
                    for ($i = 1; $i < $pathSize; $i++) {
                        $path[] = $collection->getItemById((int)$structure[$i])->getName();
                    }
                    /** @var string $index */
                    $index = $this->standardizeString(
                        implode(self::DELIMITER_CATEGORY, $path)
                    );
                    $this->categories[$index] = $category->getId();
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a category.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param int $parentId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function createCategory($name, $parentId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        if (!($parentCategory = $this->getCategoryById($parentId))) {
            $parentCategory = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($parentId);
        }
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $category->setParentId($parentId);
        $category->setName($name);
        $category->setIsActive(true);
        $category->setIncludeInMenu(false);
        $category->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
        try {
            $category->save();
            $this->categoriesCache[$category->getId()] = $category;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->addFailedCategory($category, $e);
        }

        return $category->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Returns ID of category by string path creating nonexistent ones.
     *
     * @param string $categoryPath
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function upsertCategory($categoryPath)
    {
        /** @var string $index */
        $index = $this->standardizeString($categoryPath);

        if (!isset($this->categories[$index])) {
            $pathParts = explode(self::DELIMITER_CATEGORY, $categoryPath);
            $parentId = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
            $path = '';

            foreach ($pathParts as $pathPart) {
                $path .= $this->standardizeString($pathPart);
                if (!isset($this->categories[$path])) {
                    $this->categories[$path] = $this->createCategory($pathPart, $parentId);
                }
                $parentId = $this->categories[$path];
                $path .= self::DELIMITER_CATEGORY;
            }
        }

        return $this->categories[$index];
    }

    /**
     * Returns IDs of categories by string path creating nonexistent ones.
     *
     * @param string $categoriesString
     * @param string $categoriesSeparator
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function upsertCategories($categoriesString, $categoriesSeparator)
    {
        $categoriesIds = [];
        $categories = explode($categoriesSeparator, $categoriesString);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            try {
                $categoriesIds[] = $this->upsertCategory($category);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
                $this->addFailedCategory($category, $e);
            }
        }

        return $categoriesIds;
    }

    /**
     * Add failed category
     *
     * @param string $category
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $exception
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    private function addFailedCategory($category, $exception)
    {
        $this->failedCategories[] =
            [
                'category' => $category,
                'exception' => $exception,
            ];
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return failed categories
     *
     * @return array
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function getFailedCategories()
    {
        return $this->failedCategories;
    }

    /**
     * Resets failed categories' array
     *
     * @return $this
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    public function clearFailedCategories()
    {
        $this->failedCategories = [];
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category by Id
     *
     * @param int $categoryId
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category|null
     */
    public function getCategoryById($categoryId)
    {
        return isset($this->categoriesCache[$categoryId]) ? $this->categoriesCache[$categoryId] : null;
    }

    /**
     * Standardize a string.
     * For now it performs only a lowercase action, this method is here to include more complex checks in the future
     * if needed.
     *
     * @param string $string
     * @return string
     */
    private function standardizeString($string)
    {
        return mb_strtolower($string);
    }
}
```

but can't override the model. correct me where I am wrong?

Comment: Please share the code of `Magenticians\Showcategory\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor`

Comment: i have update my question ,,  you can see 
Magenticians\Showcategory\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor code also.

Comment: You may need to use extends Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor in your class definition. It is also good to change only the required function in your override class.

Comment: when i extend ,,class CategoryProcessor extends Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor,,it give me an error :Fatal error:  Class 'Magenticians\Showcategory\Model\Import\Product\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor' not found in /var/www/html/olympic-supply-company/app/code/Magenticians/Showcategory/Model/Import/Product/CategoryProcessor.php on line 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can override protected function in magento2 like this:

Extend CategoryProcessor class with \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor

like this :

```
class CategoryProcessor extends \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product\CategoryProcessor
```

m just missing the  \ before Magento.