# What is the recommended method of overriding protected methods?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, attribute-options

I was going to create a plugin so that I could extend `Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute::_processAttributeOptions()`. However, because this method is protected, I am unable to do so.

I've added a column to the table `eav_attribute_option_value` called `api_attribute_id` and I need it to be updated when `_saveOptions()` triggers `_processAttributeOptions()`.

Is the only way for me to rewrite this method for me to use `<preference>` and provide a class that extends it?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with overriding a protected method, you just cannot override a **private** method function.

Your purpose to write the addon value to new column of table `eav_attribute_option_value` so check the logic from

```
Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute::_updateAttributeOptionValues($optionId, $values)
```

where data was insert to.

Comment: Right, we're talking about the same method but the plugin feature does not work on nonpublic methods. I am asking if implementing `<prefer>`  in di.xml is the next best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can override protected function by `<preference>`

here you can see how overriding protected methods [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256778/magento2-how-can-i-override-protected-function)